# What Font Does Jiminy's Journal Use?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-chain-of-memories

I am doing writing out all of Jiminy's journal as a personal project. What font does the journal use in Chain of Memories?

Comment: GBA or PS2 remake?

Comment: GBA, would be preferable, but either one is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font used by the GBA game is embedded into the cartridge itself, and is a custom created font for the game. It is also a pixel font, so it will not scale well too far above the size it is in the game (very small). There are many sprite ripping sites out there where you can find the font (not going to link because it is of questionable legality) if you want that exact font. However, if you just want a look-a-like, you can either just use a different [bitmap font](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php) or find a different [sans serif font](http://www.fonts.com/browse/classifications/geometric-sans).

[image: Chain of Memories Journal Screenshot]
[[Image Source]](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Jiminy%27s_Journal)